# Categorical response - Expected prediction error derivation

Tags: categorical-data, prediction

I'm stuck at the formula derivation from 2.21 to 2.22, and then 2.23.
It is from the book **The Elements of Statistical Learning**.
Any pointers or links would be much appreciated

[image]

Comment: $L(G_k, g)$ is the loss function, which would be 0 when $G_k=g$ and 1 otherwise.